# How to make a varibale+wildcard dict:fetch in Erlang

Tags: dictionary, erlang

I have the following structure of a dictionary in Erlang:

```
Key: {element_name, a, element_type, type_1}

Value: [list].

Dictionary: (({element_name, a, element_type, type_1},[List]), ({element_name, b, element_type, type_2},[List])).
```

I would like to update a certain key-value pair and insert some new data into the 'key' tuple (not into 'value' list):

```
1. Value_list = dict:fetch({element_name, a, element_type, _}, Dict).
2. Dict2 = dict:erase ({element_name, a, element_type, _}, Dict).
3. Dict3 = dict:store ({element_name, a, element_type, New_type}, Value_list, Dict2).
```

The problem is that at line 1 Erlang says that variable "_" is unbound.

It seems that I cannot fetch a value by providing only a part of the key if the key is a tuple. Is this true?

Is it actually possible to update a key in a dictionary?

Is there any shorter way to do this instead of doing 1,2 and 3?

Comment: Not putting this as an answer because it doesn't directly address your question, but IMHO if you're updating keys you're using the wrong structure. Whatever field it is you're updating should be part of the value, not the key.

Comment: What should happen if there are two keys `{element_name, a, element_type, type_1}` and `{element_name, a, element_type, type_2}`? I think Dan is right, you are using wrong key structure.

Comment: I totally agree! I have switched to another structure. It has helped me to accomplish my task. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dict doesn't support what you want to do.  you will have to know the key, erase the old key/value pair, and store a new one.

take a look at ets.  you can use ets:match to find keys that match your spec.  you'll still have to delete the old key/value pair and insert a new one.

Comment: Again `ets` doesn't allow you to *update* the key, in the same way `dict` doesn't. Even using `proplist` as @Muzaaya mentions you are not really *updating* the key but rewriting the key/value pair with a new key. You can get into trouble with doing that in `proplist` if you happen to get duplicate keys.

Answer (score -1):

If you insist on updating the Key in the dictionary without deleting it and later storing a new value against it, i suggest that you first convert your Dict into a list by this: `dict:to_list/1`. Consider this piece of code:

```
Fun_to_match_key = fun({{element_name, a, element_type, _} = Key,Value})-> 
                        %% do some stuff here with the Key and value and assuming
                        %% this fun returns the new Key-Value pair you want
                        New_Key = update_my_key(Key),
                        New_Value = update_my_value_if_need_to(Value),
                        {New_Key,New_Value};
                      (Any)-> Any
                   end,
%% Then in one operation, you convert the dict into a list, apply the 
%% fun above in a list comprehension and convert the list back to a dict

New_dict = dict:from_list([Fun_to_match_key(Key_Value_Pair) || Key_Value_Pair <- dict:to_list(Old_Dict)]),
New_dict.
```

Converting the dict into a list will give you a `proplist()` which is much easier to manipulate either Key or value. You could use any method say, recursion with several clauses in which you pattern match the nature of Key you want to manipulate, in the above example i have chosen to use a fun within a list comprehension.
That should do the trick!

Comment: I don't know why this answer got two downvotes -- the answer is not *wrong* it is just not a recommended practice. As others have noted already, if the programmer feels a need to update keys *and* values (or especially *just keys*) then dicts and maps and whatever K:V type data structure is simply the wrong sort of structure. But that does not render this answer wrong, and the question was asked in an absence of context -- so while it could be (and likely is) an X-Y problem, converting the dict to a list, performing some operation, and then converting it back is indeed the obvious approach.